# Is there any notion of Poincaré series for Hermitian modular forms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I have been studying modular forms and their generalisations for a year or so. It is a very interesting fact that the space of cusp forms $S_k$ is generated by the Poincaré series of exponential type (i.e., by $P_{k}^n(\tau)= \sum\limits_{\gamma}e^{2\pi i n \tau}|_k\gamma$, where $\gamma$ runs over the distinct cosets of stabiliser of $e^{2\pi i n \tau}$ in $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$). Similarly, Poincar'e series are defined for other kind of automorphic forms also, e.g., Jacobi forms, Siegel modular forms, Hilbert modular forms, Hermitian Jacobi forms, etc. Interestingly, I could not find similar series for **Hermitian modular forms** (although it is there for Hermitian Jacobi forms).

My questions are:

1. Is it really defined (I think so, but I could not find any paper/book on this)?
2. *(If it is not defined then) Is there any problem to define such series for Hermitian modular forms?*
3. Can anyone please give me any reference for such Poincaré series, if the notion is there in the existing literature.

Thank you so much.

Comment: There's a limit to how many particular cases it's worth writing down explicitly; at some point it becomes less effort just to formulate the definition for a general reductive group and then specialise it to the case at hand. There probably aren't any papers/books specifically treating Eisenstein series for $GL_{2024}$ either.